# Vertical expansion of column within grid layout using CSS

Tags: html, css, grid-layout

*This is some sort of advanced CSS, so hold on to your butts!*

I have a grid of three columns. Two of those columns contain text, and one contains nothing. The goal of this exercise is to get the empty column to expand vertically to the height of the tallest column. In other words, the empty column should vertically expand into the row div. Why? Google AdSense dynamic ad sizes, of course.

Now, I've seen some similar questions out there, but I believe this situation to be unique due to the left float on the columns. I can get this done with JavaScript, but I'm looking for a CSS solution.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/deqbgaoc/2/)

HTML:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='column'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div class='column empty'>
            <!-- empty, but needs to expand into vertical space -->
        </div>
        <div class='column'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        <div class='floatclear'>
            <!-- just to help show the structure -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class='floatclear'>
        <!-- just to help show the structure -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    text-align:justify;
}
.container {
    padding:24px 0;
    background-color:#DEA5A4;
}
.row {
    padding:0 24px;
    background-color:#CFCFC4;
}
.column {
    padding:24px;
    background-color:#CB99C9;
    float:left;
    width:33.333%;
}
.empty {
    border:#FDFD96 dotted 3px;
}
.floatclear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add the following css attribute to the .row class

```
display: flex;
```

The following browsers support flexbox: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

http://jsfiddle.net/deqbgaoc/3/